# Uncaught Type Error: recipes .map is not a function. I am trying to map my data

Tags: reactjs, database, fetch

This is my Recipe List file, I am trying to map my recipe fetched data in it, I will give my recipe MongoDB schema if that would help. My recipe Model has only the html for how the card would look like, and I am passing the recipe prop of course.

I am new to React.js. I don't know how to fix.

```
import "./RecipeList.css";
import { Link, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import React, { useEffect, useLayoutEffect, useState } from 'react';
import RecipeModel from "../Recipe/RecipeModel/RecipeModel";

const RecipeList = () => {
    
    const [recipes,setRecipes] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('http://localhost:3005/api/recipes?page=1&limit=10')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(result => {
            setRecipes(result)
        });
    },[]);

    // useLayoutEffect(() => {
    //     window.scrollTo(0, 0)
    // });

   
    return (
        <div>
           <section className="sec4">
           <h1>Caponata pasta</h1>
           {recipes.map(x=> <RecipeModel key ={x._id} recipe={x}/>)}
    </section>
    <section className="sec5nav">
    <ul>
            <li><Link smooth= "true" to="/"><i className="fas fa-solid fa-book-bookmark"></i></Link>Home</li>
            <li><Link smooth= "true" to="/recipes"><i className="fas fa-thin fa-bowl-rice"></i></Link>Recipes</li>
            <li><Link smooth= "true" to="/personal-list"><i className="fas fa-solid fa-list-ul"></i></Link>Your Recipes</li>
            <li><Link smooth= "true" to="/favourites"><i className="fa-solid fa-heart"></i></Link>Favourites</li>
            <li><Link smooth= "true" to="/create-recipe"><i className="fas fa-solid fa-plus"></i></Link>Add Recipe</li>
            <li><Link smooth= "true" to="/user-profile"><i className="fas fa-solid fa-user"></i></Link>Your Profile</li>
        </ul>
        <a href="#" className="to-top" id ="to-top">
    <i className="fas fa-chevron-up"></i>
  </a>
        </section>
        </div>
    );
}

export default RecipeList;
```

This is my Recipe Model, my recipe schema for Mongo Db

```
    const { Schema, model } = require('mongoose');

const recipeSchema = new Schema(
    {
      name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minLength: [2, 'Name should be at least 5 characters long!'],
      },
      time: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minLength: [2, 'Time should be in the format(10min)!'],
      },
      imageUrl: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        match: [/^https?:\/\/.+/, 'ImageUrl is not valid!'],
      },
      ingredients: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minLength: [5, 'Ingredients should be at least 5 characters long!'],
      },
      instructions: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minLength: [10, 'Instructions should be at least 10 characters long!'],
      },
      isDeleted: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false,
      },
    },
    { timestamps: true }
  );
  
  const recipeModel = model('Recipe', recipeSchema);
  module.exports = {
    recipeModel,
  };
```

This is the console screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Add a console.log(result) before this line setRecipes(result) and check whether result is an array or not ?

Comment: yes it is I got this message {recipes: Array(5), count: 14}

Comment: it seems like an object to me

Comment: how can i fix it,i read almost everything about this error,i implemented other logic to take the data but nothing

Comment: instead of setting setRecipes(result), set it to setRecipes(result.recipes}

Comment: thank you so much it showed the data,but in my postman result after sending the object i see all of the fields,but in my web console,it shows only the instructions...any idea why, i will add a screenshot to the post

Comment: Take a look at your console carefully, it is showing other fields as well like id, createdAt

Comment: I know about those,in my schema i have also the fields name,time,imageUrl and ingredients it doesn't show them even in the postman when i call out the database, it shows only the fields in the screenshot

Comment: in the postman it's giving you all the fields ?

Comment: no it doesn't.it gives me the same fields as the console, but when i sent POST the object ,it returns the data model correctly  with all of the fields, when i call out the whole collection it does not, only id and instructions and etc

Comment: Then check you fetchAll() contoller function thats is getting executed when you are sending a fetchAll() request. compare it with post request functionHandler

Answer (score 0):

Since you get an object in your state as you mentioned in comments.
Use

```
recipes.recipes.map(item=>{
<RecipeModel recipe={item}/>
})
```